# Multiple window definitions at the end of the query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, window-functions

In Oracle another way to write a window function is something like this:

```
Select  a
           first_value(b) over w,
           first_value(c) over w
 from table 
window w as (partition by d order by e)
```

I find this very useful when I have to calculate several columns over the same partition. However, I wonder if it is possible to have more than one window definition at the end of the query.

```
Select  a
           first_value(b) over w,
           first_value(c) over w,
           first_value(h) over t,
           first_value(i) over t
from table 
window w as (partition by d order by e)
window t as (partition by f order by g)
```

I think the code becomes easier to understand, instead of writing the partition definition in from of every column for the second window definition (t).

Regards

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I've got an error, But I do not know if this is because it is not possible, or maybe I'm writing it wrong

Comment: i think your best option is to simulate/emulate MySQL 8.0 Names windows is to use common table expression (CTE) (`WITH <name> AS (...)` syntax) in Oracle but i very much doubt the syntax will be as easy as that syntax as you might need a JOIN after

Comment: That is not remotely Oracle syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is MySQL 8's syntax your are mixing it up. 
I think you saw this [manual page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/window-functions-frames.html) which is about MySQL 8 database not Oracle database, as MySQL database is also owned by Oracle corp.

Query

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(a."profit") OVER w
FROM 
 a 
WINDOW w as (PARTITION BY a."year")
```

Will result into a error `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` on Oracle database see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7772e/1)

Where

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(a.profit) OVER w
FROM 
 a 
WINDOW w as (PARTITION BY a.year)
```

will work just fine on MySQL 8.0 see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5wq8KEkCA9wi39awfSetF2/0)

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to do something like that, I have tried but I've got always an error message. Maybe (if this is possible) I'm writing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Though [ANSI SQL 2003](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003) officially introduced window functions to the SQL language as the standard and does support the `WINDOW` clause, only a few DBMS' actually integrated the clause into their dialects including Postgres, Sybase Anywhere, SQLite, and now recently MySQL. The other majors, Oracle, DB2, and SQL Server, appear to not support the `WINDOW` clause.

- [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-window.html)
- [Sybase Anywhere docs](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/fr/dbreference_fr11/window-statement.html)
- [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/windowfunctions.html)

As a result, you need to rewrite the window for every aggregate use in Oracle.

Comment: But at least you have window functions. MS Access 2019 (among the top 10 DBMS' in the world) *still* does not support window functions, CTEs, or other current standards. Please join vote, share, comment my [ticket](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) to the Access team to update its dialect.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
WINDOW window_name AS (window_spec)
    [, window_name AS (window_spec)] ...
```

You need a comma between the Windows:

```
Select  a
           first_value(b) over w,
           first_value(c) over w,
           first_value(h) over t,
           first_value(i) over t
from table 
window w as (partition by d order by e), t as (partition by f order by g)
```

Comment: this is the right answer, based on the actual question, just removing the second "window" keyword and adding a comma